# jQuery: add clone to container

Tags: jquery, clone

Is there other ways to add a cloned element to an container than:

```
$(".product").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});

$("#container").append(ui.draggable.clone());
```

append just puts the element after the last element in #container. I want to decide where the position should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `before()` or `after()` to insert an element at a specific position.

```
$(".product").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});

$("#container #target").after(ui.draggable.clone());
```

Comment: Thanks :) that was one way to do it. Alos I find that you can use insertAfter + insertBefore.